Can data transformations be done using python/SQL in Lakehouse/warehouse and vice versa?
I'm new the Azure Lakehouse and warehouse. I'm trying to grasp the concept in Microsoft Fabric workspace so that I can choose either lakehouse or warehouse to be my destination.
I understand that Lakehouse is combination of data lake and warehouse and hence supports both structured and unstructured data.
I also know that Lakehouse is based on spark engine, and warehouse is based on SQL engine.
This pyspark is used for transformations in Lakehouse, and SQL is used for transformations in warehouse.
I also know that Lakehouse supports using SQL queries (SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) via pyspark, and simple SELECT queries using %%sql.
I want to ask:

Can I write data transformation SQL (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) using %%sql in Lakehouse?
Can I write data transformation using python pyspark or notebooks in Warehouse?


Have you tried anything and facing any error?

I'm just trying to get my head around this

For your two questions:

Can I write data transformation SQL (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) using %%sql
in Lakehouse?

Yes, you can do data transformation in Spark SQL beyond SELECT's, for example MERGE, INSERT and DELETE as supported by the Spark SQL API, but these will have to be delta tables.

Can I write data transformation using python pyspark or notebooks in
Warehouse?

Not directly, this is limited to the supported T-SQL features. You can fire up a note book in the Lakehouse, and connect to the Warehouse using a JDBC connection, and run T-SQL wrapped in python to run transformations, but there is no direct support for running a python command in the Warehouse experience.

But in the warehouse I can use the pipeline containing the pyspark notebook. So why do you say not directly?

You cannot run Python in the Warehouse, like you can in the Lakehouse (You are not moving the data out of the lake house part), It just becomes another SQL source for your data. You have to extract via a JDBC Connection to a data frame or lakehouse table, do the transformation and write it back, your not running the pyhton on the warehouse directly.  As mentioned you do have the ability to run a SQL Query to the warehouse using a JDBC Connection Query, but again, your not using PySpark/Python features, just running the same SQL you would run on the warehouse.


In a notebook within the Lakehouse, you can execute SELECT queries using the %%sql magic command. However, data transformation queries such as  UPDATE, and DELETE are currently not supported directly with %%sql in Lakehouse.

The Warehouse in Microsoft Fabric is based on the SQL engine, which is optimized for relational queries and transformations using T-SQL. So, you cannot directly use PySpark or Spark-based transformations in the Warehouse.


I performed the update using pyspark the below as an example Using notebook:
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("/lakehouse/delta/d01")
df_updated = df.withColumn("age", 
                when(df.name == "Dilip", 32).otherwise(df.age))
df_updated.show()
df_updated.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/lakehouse/delta/d01")

Results:

+---+-------+---+
| id|   name|age|
+---+-------+---+
|  3|Narayan| 40|
|  1|  Dilip| 32|
|  2|    Raj| 25|
+---+-------+---+

When I tried to perform update & delete Using the %%SQL
%%sql
UPDATE sample_table
SET age = 32
WHERE name = 'dilip';

Error:

UPDATE destination only supports Delta sources. Some(HiveTableRelation
[spark_catalog.default.sample_table,
org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, Data Cols:
[id#1336, name#1337, age#1338], Partition Cols: []] )

%%sql
DELETE FROM sample_table
WHERE name = 'narayan';

ERROR:

[INTERNAL_ERROR] Unexpected table relation: HiveTableRelation
[spark_catalog.default.sample_table,
org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, Data Cols:
[id#1342, name#1343, age#1344], Partition Cols: []]

I have performed the INSERT,DELETE using Pyspark since the table is in delta format
INSERT Script:
new_data = [Row(id=4, name="Dileep", age=28)]
new_df = spark.createDataFrame(new_data)
df_existing = spark.read.format("delta").load("/lakehouse/delta/d01")
df_combined = df_existing.union(new_df)
df_combined.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/lakehouse/delta/d01")

DELETE Script:
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("/lakehouse/delta/d01")
df_filtered = df.filter(df.name != "Narayan")
df_filtered.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/lakehouse/delta/d01")

Final Results:
+---+------+---+
| id|  name|age|
+---+------+---+
|  4|Dileep| 28|
|  1| Dilip| 32|
|  2|   Raj| 25|
+---+------+---+


To update a delta table from an arbitrary Dataframe use merge instead of update.  See example here: https://github.com/dbrownems/SparkDataEngineeringForSQLServerProfessionals/blob/main/Presentation.ipynb

Does %%sql in Lakehouse means TSQL or SparkSQL?

What do you mean by you cannot directly use PySpark or Spark-based transformations in the Warehouse - I'm asking because I can use a pipeline containing a Pyspark notebook.

@variable %%SQL is Spark SQL

@variable Pipelines are not limited to Warehouse, it is basically an orchestration tool. I have pipeline that dump data from and API to the lake house, run a notebook to update the lake house, then use a copy activity to a database or warehouse

Api is structured data. You load it into warehouse purely so that you can use the notebook for updates? Why not directly load into warehouse?

The answer to your question is yes like others have pointed out.
If you are inclined to use both together, which is what some people do depending on their comfort level, you can do the below -
lets say you read data into pyspark dataframe, then use createOrReplaceTempView or the globaltempview. Write SQL on top of it and execute your transformation.
then push the dataframe back to the destination either in lakehouse or datawarehouse.
