How to use python data frame in fabric warehouse?
I'm using fabric warehouse to extract, transform and load data into the warehouse tables.
The primary language is SQL, and much of the work is done using SQL stored procedures.
I'm interested to use python, data frame to perform the extract, transform and load on a few tables.

Is ot possible to use python/dataframe in the fabric warehouse?

Or do I need to switch from fabric warehouse to fabric Lakehouse to be able to use python/dataframe?

Or is there any common layer wherein table's can be shared between warehouse and Lakehouse? So that I can use both: SQL stored procedures and python dataframe?



Isn't this question a reframing of this question you posted?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79097923/can-data-transformations-be-done-using-python-sql-in-lakehouse-warehouse-and-vic
There is no common layer, and getting data from SQL to Spark Then Back to Spark, isn't an efficient way of doing it

Yes, It is possible to use Python and DataFrames in Microsoft Fabric to extract, transform, and load data on tables without switching from fabric warehouse to fabric Lakehouse.
It can be done by using the Spark connector for Microsoft Fabric Synapse Data Warehouse to access and work with data from the warehouse using Python. It allows to perform extract, transform, and load using PySpark and Pandas DataFrames.

So where do I place this spark connector? In a notebook? Does fabric warehouse support python notebook?

Details are here, it just allows a simple set up of connections, rather that using the jdbc way of connectiong and running code. Its more for reading data from the DWH, not processing it and returning it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/data-engineering/spark-data-warehouse-connector
